# Devices supporting CMSensorRecorder

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, apple-watch

I haven't been able to find the list of devices supporting the new [CMSensorRecorder API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMSensorRecorder_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CMSensorRecorder) (iOS 9+). From a [WWDC video (around 8 minutes in)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=705) it seems like its only available on Watch.

Which devices support this API?

Comment: Tested and API is not available on iPhone 6

Comment: Tested and API still not avilable on iphone 6 and IOS9.0

Answer (score 6):

CMSensorRecorder is only supported on the Apple Watch. iOS has had the same API since iOS 9.0.... but no iOS devices support it. If you'd like to have the API be supported on iOS, please file a bug with [bugreport.apple.com](https://bugreport.apple.com) and reach out to me at [cmsr@cambridgesoftwareinc.com](http://cmsensorrecorder@cambridgesoftwareinc.com)

The [CMSensorRecorder.isAccelerometerRecordingAvailable()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMSensorRecorder_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CMSensorRecorder/isAccelerometerRecordingAvailable) function indicates whether a specific device supports the feature. The APIs have a minimum OS version in the header files: iOS 9.0 or watchOS 2.0. However this is a minimal but not sufficient requirement as support varies by both device and OS version.

- iPhone 5S           - No (iOS 9.3)
- iPhone 6 (Plus)   - No (iOS 9.3)
- iPhone 6S (Plus) - No (iOS 10.0.2)
- iPhone 7              - No (iOS 10.0.2)
- iPad Pro              - Unconfirmed (No Expected)
- Apple Watch       - Yes (watchOS 2.0)

For watchOS, the recording frequency varies. For watchOS 2.0, it records at 25 hertz. For watchOS 3.0, it records at 50 hertz.

Comment: iPhone 5S - iOS 9.3 - Not available

Answer (score 1):

It is available on all devices with A10 CPU and later (iPhone 7, 8, X, XS) and iOS11 and up + Apple Watch with watchOS 2.0 and up.

Doc say it is available from iOS9.0, but to really have it reported as available by CMSensorRecorder.isAccelerometerRecordingAvailable() you have to have iOS11.

Answer (score -3):

You need to check `CMSensorRecorder.h` file and there you can find following lines:

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE(NA, 9_0) __WATCHOS_AVAILABLE(2.0)
@interface CMSensorRecorder : NSObject
```

So, it mean that this class is available an all devices which are running iOS 9.0+ and WatchOS 2.0+

Comment: It is true that the API is available on these devices, but the underlying capability is not.